# Does a multi-value purrr::pluck exist?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Seems like a basic question and perhaps I'm just missing something obvious ... but is there any way to `pluck` a sublist (with `purrr`)?
More specifically, here's an initial list:

```
l <- list(a = "foo", b = "bar", c = "baz")
```

And I want to return a new (sub-)list with only elements `a` and `b`.
Normally, I'd just do 'base' R sub-listing:

```
l[c("a", "b")]
```

But this doesn't provide the nice `.default` handling of `pluck`.
My understanding is that pluck 'replaces' `[[`, but is there a `purrr` equivalent for replacing `[`?

Comment: I don't think a direct 'replacement' for `[` exists, at least not in `purrr`. I guess a workaround would be `map(set_names(c("a", "b", "z")), partial(pluck, l), .default = "Not found!")` but that's not very neat!

Answer (score 9):

Similar to jzadra's post, you could also do:

```
l %>% keep(names(.) %in% c("a","b"))
```

Comment: This is a great solution but FYI it does not (currently) work when using the native pipe operator, `|>` (sadface).

Comment: This doesn't retain the order in the list of names unfortunately, which can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my take on it. Not based on `purrr` thus slightly off topic, but compatible with the `tidyverse`'s general interface principle of playing nicely with pipes.

```r
pluck_multiple <- function(x, ...) {
  `[`(x, ...)
}

x <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = list(x = TRUE, y = FALSE))

pluck_multiple(x, c("a", "b"))
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
pluck_multiple(x, 2:3)
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $c
#> $c$x
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $c$y
#> [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that `purrr::keep()` does what you want.

`l %>% keep(names(.) == "a" | names(.) == "b")`

Comment: Or `keep(names(.) %in% c("a", "b"))`

Answer (score 2):

There's clearly a need for "muti-value pluck". It really comes down to extending flexibility of "pluck" to retrieving multiple values from the same level of list, as described in [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/223) github issue. For the example above, you can probably get away with:

```
> purrr::map(purrr::set_names(c("a", "b")), 
          ~purrr::pluck(l, .x, .default = NA_character_))
#> $a
#> [1] "foo"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off Rappster, if you don't mind the ugliness, you could pipe to the functional form of the extraction operator as a one-off:

```
> list(a = 1, b = 2, c = list(x = TRUE, y = FALSE)) %>% `[`(c('a', 'b'))
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

> list(a = 1, b = 2, c = list(x = TRUE, y = FALSE)) %>% `[`(2:3)
$b
[1] 2

$c
$c$x
[1] TRUE

$c$y
[1] FALSE
```

This has the added benefit of keeping the order of your inputs vs the `keep` approach, or allowing repeated extractions:

```
> c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) %>% `[`(2:3)
b c 
2 3 
> c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) %>% `[`(3:2)
c b 
3 2 
> c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) %>% keep(names(.) %in% c('a', 'b'))
a b 
1 2 
> c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) %>% keep(names(.) %in% c('b', 'a'))
a b 
1 2 
> c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) %>% `[`(c('a', 'a'))
a a 
1 1 
> c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) %>% keep(names(.) %in% c('a', 'a'))
a 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not purrr, but magrittr has `extract()` as an alias for `[`:

```r
library(magrittr)

l %>% 
  extract(c("a", "b"))
# $a
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $b
# [1] "bar"
```

magrittr implements [a number of other pipeable operator aliases](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/aliases.html), too.