# Remove an element of a list by name

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working with a long named list and I'm trying to keep/remove elements that match a certain name, within a tidyverse context, similar to

```
dplyr::select(contains("pattern"))
```

However, I'm having issues figuring it out.

```
library(tidyverse)

a_list <- 
  list(a = "asdfg",
       b = "qwerty",
       c = "zxcvb")

a_list %>% pluck("a") # works
a_list %>% pluck(contains("a")) #does not work

a_list[2:3] # this is what I want
a_list %>% pluck(-"a") # but this does not work
```

Comment: Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983716/does-a-multi-value-purrrpluck-exist), it sounds like `pluck` is a replacement for `[[` not `[` and so there isn't a built-in way to accomplish `a_list[2:3]`. `[[` only selects [one element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169495/8099834)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To remove by name you could use:

```
a_list %>% purrr::list_modify("a" = NULL)
$`b`
[1] "qwerty"

$c
[1] "zxcvb"
```

I'm not sure the other answers are using the name of the element, rather than the element itself for selection. The example you gave is slightly confusing since the element 'a' both contains 'a' in it's value AND is called 'a'. So it's easy to get mixed up. To show the difference I'll modify the example slightly.

```
b_list <- 
  list(a = "bsdfg",
       b = "awerty",
       c = "zxcvb")

b_list %>% purrr::list_modify("a" = NULL)
```

returns

```
$`b`
[1] "awerty"

$c
[1] "zxcvb"
```

but

```
purrr::discard(b_list,.p = ~stringr::str_detect(.x,"a"))
```

returns

```
$`a`
[1] "bsdfg"

$c
[1] "zxcvb"
```

Comment: purrr [now recommends](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/list_assign.html#arguments) using `rlang::zap` to remove values, e.g. `b_list %>% purrr::list_modify("a" = rlang::zap())`

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but one simple way to do this :

```
a_list[['a']] <- NULL
```

Comment: Base code is often the most efficient! (in terms of typing)

Answer (score 14):

Keeping it full tidyverse, you could do,

```
purrr::discard(a_list,.p = ~stringr::str_detect(.x,"a"))
```

Comment: If your code/package doesn't have stringr as a dependency: `purrr::discard(a_list,.p = ~grepl("a", .x))`

Answer (score 5):

using base R:

```
a_list[!grepl("a",unlist(a_list))]
$b
[1] "qwerty"

$c
[1] "zxcvb"
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to previous answer but searching names as in OP

```
within(a_list, rm(a))

a_list[!grepl("^a$",names(a_list))]
a_list[grepl("^a$",names(a_list))]<-NULL

a_list[-which(names(a_list)=="a")]
a_list[-which(names(a_list)!="a")]<-NULL
a_list[ which(names(a_list)=="a")]<-NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Parisa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091228/854988), just fits better into `tidyverse` pipe chains:

```
library(magrittr)

a_list <-
    list(a = "asdfg",
         b = "qwerty",
         c = "zxcvb")

a_list %>%
magrittr::inset(c('a', 'c'), NULL)
```

Another alternative notation:

```
a_list %>%
`[<-`(c('a', 'b'), NULL)
```